# pdfminer mixes order of lines

Tags: pdfminer, pdfminersix

I'm extracting pdf using pdfminersix.
I have following text:
[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yI86U.png)

after parsing it my result is as below:

```
Nr 48. Promująco na rozwój chorób alergicznych i wystąpienie objawów alergii 
działa zwiększenie aktywności/ilości: 

1) limfocytów Th1; 
2) limfocytów Th2; 
3) limfocytów Th17; 
Prawidłowa odpowiedź to: 
B. tylko 2. 
A. 1,4. 

4) IL-5. 
5) IL-12. 

C. 1,3. 

D. 2,4. 

E. 3,5.
```

The order of the lines is mixed. Is there a way to prevent it? For example to force pdfminer to read the file line by line. I have tried to convert pdf to html, but the result is a mess of seperate span tags for each word.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i 've found a solution by increasing char_margin to 20 in LaParams

```
laparams = LAParams(char_margin = 20)
```

Comment: Note: Just because the text has a certain sequence on the page doesn't mean it has the same sequence in the file. (I'm not familiar with pdfminer - which sounds really useful - but it might not do a grand job of sorting the fragments.)